# WebStorm hang in Linux every 5-15 minutes

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

WebStorm hang in Linux every 5-15 minutes. the thread dump file is as follows

1. The recently dump file [one file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xinmeng1/958d112b8127b2ae6602cb0bd5f2dfac/raw/b868277ff508ad1d1c9f530b1f1f5cb85d0f2f32/thread%2520dump%2520files)
2. The full version is
   attached (the dump files for nearly 1 hour) [dump file
   download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp8ic2hkv5ua77s/threadDumps-20160817-131259-WS-162.1447.27.tar.gz?dl=0)):

I have tried lots of solutions to modify the configuration file such as change the Xms2g Xmx2g, but it didn't work.

By the way, some of my friends has same issue and they said it may be the JDK8 issue probably. Meanwhile, the other Jetbrain product has the same issue.

```
    "AWT-EventQueue-0 2016.2.1#WS-162.1447.27 WebStorm, eap:false, os:Linux 4.4.0-34-generic, java-version:JetBrains s.r.o 1.8.0_76-release-b216" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 waiting on condition
     java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
 on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2e970c27
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.awtLockWait(SunToolkit.java:267)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.getCurrentServerTime(XToolkit.java:1462)
    at sun.awt.X11.XClipboard.setContentsNative(XClipboard.java:93)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(SunClipboard.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl.f(CaretImpl.java:1249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl.a(CaretImpl.java:1239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl$$Lambda$370/774284532.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretModelImpl.doWithCaretMerging(CaretModelImpl.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl.a(CaretImpl.java:1147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl.setSelection(CaretImpl.java:1137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.CaretImpl.setSelection(CaretImpl.java:1129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.SelectionModelImpl.setSelection(SelectionModelImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.a(EditorImpl.java:4636)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.e(EditorImpl.java:4548)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.a(EditorImpl.java:4394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$$Lambda$852/372658132.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.k(EditorImpl.java:4394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.access$13000(EditorImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyMouseMotionListener.mouseDragged(EditorImpl.java:6193)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6581)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:863)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:695)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:385)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

"ApplicationImpl pooled thread 33" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 runnable
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


"ApplicationImpl pooled thread 30" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 runnable
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.ThreadDumper.dumpThreadsToFile(ThreadDumper.java:58)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.ThreadDumper.getThreadDumpInfo(ThreadDumper.java:48)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.dumpThreads(PerformanceWatcher.java:273)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.b(PerformanceWatcher.java:230)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.c(PerformanceWatcher.java:210)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.access$000(PerformanceWatcher.java:58)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher$1.run(PerformanceWatcher.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"process reaper" prio=0 tid=0x0 nid=0x0 runnable
     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 (in native)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitForProcessExit(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$initStreams$3(UNIXProcess.java:290)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess$$Lambda$20/966209523.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you please send the content of your IDE log folder (menu Help - Show log) to our tech support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us They will have a closer look. Thanks!
In the meantime, please try running WebStorm with another JDK (Ctrl-Shift-Enter - Switch IDE boot JDK).

Comment: Yes, I had submitted a request on the support website. I will try the different JDK version later. thanks